# How exactly this code works?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, sml, ml

I know how the code works except the **x** variable here: SOME y => SOME (**x**::y)

```
fun same_string(s1 : string, s2 : string) =
    s1 = s2

fun all_except_option (str, xs) = 
    case xs of 
    [] => NONE 
     | (x::xs') => case (same_string(str,x)) of 
               true => SOME xs' 
            | false => case all_except_option(str,xs') of 
                   NONE => NONE 
                    | SOME y=> SOME (x::y)
```

How **"x"** holds ["a","b"] elements when you return SOME(x::y)?

```
val test1 = all_except_option("string", ["a","b","string","c"]) = SOME ["a","b","c"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. `y` has the list `["b","c"]` bound to it, and `x` has `"a"` bound to it.

Taking `x::y` then gives the list `"a"::["b","c"] = ["a","b","c"]`.

Stepping through the code from the beginning:

`"string" <> "a"`, so a recursive call is made.
`"string" <> "b"`, so another recursive call is made.
`"string = "string"`, so `SOME ["c"]` is returned from the first recursive call.
Now, `x` holds `"b"` and `y` holds `["c"]` in the first recursive call, and so
`SOME "b"::["c"] = SOME ["b","c"]` is returned.
Finally, `x` holds `"a"` and `y` holds `["b","c"]` in the top-level call, and so
`SOME "a"::["b","c"] = SOME ["a","b","c"]` is returned from that call to be the final result.